Как найти откуда берётся сертификат SCEP?
Пытаюсь решить проблему с "экраном смерти"(86 ошибка винды). Решения в интернете разные,кто-то на оперативу скидывает,кто-то на AMD fTPM. железо-на амд(и видео и проц),оперативу менял(ошибка была и до замены),винду переставлял,дрова разных весрий ставил. Суть вопроса-подскажите что делать с проблемой или расскажите где искать этот сертификат(и почему его нет)? (триггер ошибки-запуск игр,не важно производительных или нет, либо после самого запуска,либо в течении 2 минут после) (полный код ошибки ниже)
Сбой инициализации регистрации сертификата SCEP WORKGROUP\LAPTOP-2N8C41ER$ через https://AMD-KeyId-8a0578cf56146fea399af903fb5b0ac36eb2786a.microsoftaik.azure.net/templates/Aik/scep:

GetCACaps
GetCACaps: Not Found
{"Message":"The authority \"amd-keyid-8a0578cf56146fea399af903fb5b0ac36eb2786a.microsoftaik.azure.net\" does not exist."}
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2024 15:04:53 GMT
Content-Length: 121
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
x-ms-request-id: b4b5ea8e-6682-4e93-a916-de3fe17091d0

Метод: GET(469ms)
Стадия: GetCACaps
Не найдено (404). 0x80190194 (-2145844844 HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND)

(Дополнено)
пробовал ещё экспериментировать с драйверами,при установке старых версий-зависание сопровождается синим экраном и жалобой на драйвер видеокарты, полученный после минидамп говорит о следующем-драйвер видеокарты входит в бесконечный цикл.
Дополнение к этой проблеме:

если отключить дискретную видеокарту-ошибка не появляется(зависаний нет)
есть нюансы с установкой драйверов. А конкретнее-если ставить драйвер в обычной среде появляется новая ошибка в диспетчере устройств по видеокарте(если же устанавливать в безопасной среде-ошибки с запуском нет,оно просто не запускает этот PCI):


Возникла проблема с запуском устройства
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6987&SUBSYS_134E1025&REV_C3\4&1a11cb31&0&0009.
Имя драйвера: oem0.inf (может различаться,были oem3.inf и oem45.inf,но ругалось на это же устройство)
GUID класса: {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Служба: amdwddmg
Нижние фильтры: 
Верхние фильтры: 
Проблема: 0x15
Состояние проблемы: 0x0


Экспериментировал дальше,обновил винду до 11,краши стали чаще,те же самые ошибки(что в начале описаны)
Проблема с дровами решилась случайно(в очередной раз переставлял дрова-всё встало без ошибок)
Итог-вырубил дискретку,остался на интегряшке,жду чуда или совета

Строго говоря, следует обратиться в техподдержку производителя: amdrussia. Причиной послужило, скорее всего обновление ОС от производителя MS. Из-за чего драйвер AMD устройства конфликтует с компонентами ОС. Я бы пробовал откатился назад (SystemRestore); обновить драйвера, отключить поддержку TPM модулей на системной плате.

@Daemon-5 проблема в том,что и с драйверами разбирался и разные ставил,винду тоже откатывал. ТРМ модули...тут вообще жуть,в биосе fТРМ нет,а в ОС имеется только ТРМ. от того и ищу прочих решений,но причина,предполагаю, ваша подходит под проблему
